# Getting 403 when doing an invite call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When calling `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/invite`
on a folder in a Microsoft Office 365 Group SharePoint site the response code is `403`.

If we try the same from the SharePoint UI, everything works fine.

Here is the response:

```
{,…} 
error: {code: "accessDenied", message: "The caller does not have permission to perform the action.",…} 
code: "accessDenied" 
innerError: {request-id: "0f6b7724-ff9f-4ed6-9f78-31dcb452682e", date: "2019-01-25T09:08:00"} 
message: "The caller does not have permission to perform the action." 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "accessDenied",
    "message": "The caller does not have permission to perform the action.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "0f6b7724-ff9f-4ed6-9f78-31dcb452682e",
      "date": "2019-01-25T09:08:00"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you either the user you're authenticated as does not have permission to share that file or you failed to request the [`Files.ReadWrite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#files-permissions) scope when you authenticated the user.

You need to have at least `Files.ReadWrite` consented and in your access token before you can [send a sharing invitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: The permissions scopes are in place. This only happens for this tenant and it seems to be related to that there are Guests in the group that the invite call is done for. The invite is done for an Office 365 group. @marc-lafleur

Comment: Is it possible to look up the request id on your end? This is creating significant issues for us at important large clients. The Microsoft Graph has only one way of adding permissions and that is through the invite call. If we cant rely on that it is quite crippling.

Comment: Is the user executing this action a Guest? I can see errors in the log but I cannot see any personally identifiable information (for obvious security reasons).

Comment: Also, I assume this user is an owner of the Group in question and this is a Unified group?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @MarcLaFleur. The user executing this is an Owner in the Unified Group yes. I think the problem might be related to that there are guests in the group.

Comment: Does this tenant have external sharing disabled? I wouldn't think this would apply to Guest accounts (i.e. they're not external in the way external sharing considers someone external) but it might explain the behavior.

Comment: This is a huge tenant so we dont really have insight into their external sharing policies, but the strange thing is that everything works fine if we do the same Sharing operation manually on the folder in SharePoint. Now we are also experiencing this issue at another client, so it seems to be a general issue @MarcLaFleur

Comment: Now it is happening at another tenant with no guests in the group. We are doing this invite call: : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!_3bm2fwnEESgAsUR80uffd4sllYONxZClICTDXA26oyiriXdXFB3QK9jHvTn2gen/items/01VDJPSDO2SS5APZ4ZURBKVD5XOKVTZHZS/invite
{"recipients":[{"email":"Operations@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"}],"message":"","requireSignIn":true,"sendInvitation":false,"roles":["write"]}

@MarcLaFleur

Comment: And getting this response again: Getting this response: "error": {
    "code": "accessDenied",
    "message": "The caller does not have permission to perform the action.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "f0c8db92-2d9d-4ef4-aa23-dcac1ee5c731",
      "date": "2019-02-05T14:50:32"
    }
  }
} @MarcLaFleur

Comment: Given that this is happening in some tenants and not others, you may need to open a ticket with Microsoft so they can track down the root cause. I'm not seeing anything jumping out at me.